# Storing data from MongoDB to state - best option

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mern

I'm a newcomer to the MERN stack and just putting a little blog site project together for some practice...

In my case, I'm retrieving all the blog posts to list briefly on the home screen each with a link to the full blog article. In this case the data is already retrieved and stored in React state.

Question is, when I go to the full blog article is it better to take the data from the already retrieved full list of blogs saved in state or should I get the individual blog entry from the database again with using ID.

I'm confident implementing either - I'm just considering the best practice, or benefits/dangers of doing either? Could data get out of sync?

I'm a newbie - be gentle!
Thanks for all advice.

Comment: It depends - will the data be likely to change a lot? If so, it might be better to re-fetch the article from the db as it might've become out of sync by the time the user loads it up. If not, it might not be worth it to call the db again for data you already have.

Comment: Another thing to consider is, what happens if a user navigates to a specific blogpost directly? You won't have fetched the blogposts from the homescreen so you might want a fallback option where if the blog doesn't exist in state then you fetch it from the db directly.

Comment: Thanks James - that's a great response, I hadn't considered that situation. I'll implement getting the data again.

Answer (score 0):

I think when fetching all blogs for home page, you should only fetch the data which you will show for each blog rather than fetching the whole blog.
Lets assume each of your blog has following fields:

```
{
  "title" : "Title of blog",
  "body" : "This is my blog, ...."
  "comments": [comment1, comment2, ...]
  "upvotes" : [],
  "downvotes" : [],
  "author" : ObjectId("ref to the author schema"),
  "time" : 10:30 PM
}
```

on home page, i'm assuming you only need to show the author, title, time and some lines of the body so you need to only fetch those instead of getting the whole blog.
For that you can use .select() function of mongoose:

```
const blogs = await Blogs.find({}).select({ title: 1, time: 1, body: 1, author: 1 });
```

This way, you will only be getting the data you require. By implementing this, when a user clicks on a blog to view it, you can re-fetch the whole blog and get the latest result (in case the blog was updated or new comments/votes were added, the changes will be reflected).
Hope this answers your question.